# echoing javascript not displaying any data

Tags: php

I am confused as to why this piece of simple code is not displaying any data in either console.log or .actions class. There are no errors in console and I can see the correct value being returned in the payload window in inspector.

I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks

```
<?php

    $value = '10';

    echo '<script>';
    echo 'var value = ' . json_encode($value) . ';';
    echo '$(".actions").text(value);';
    echo 'console.log(value);';
    echo '</script>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more. Maybe the script that load this script? AJAX call?

Comment: @Charis There is no script or ajax.Just trying to figure out why this is not displaying the data. thanks

Comment: Seems you not included js file for jquery ? Include                                          
                                                                                                                     
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
       </script>                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                 
  at begining and try.

Comment: @AnjaliPatil It is included in the header file. Thanks

Comment: because of jquery file not included try change position of  echo 'console.log(value);';
    echo '$(".actions").text(value);'; you will get result 10 in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that jQuery is imported before your script, try this example.

```
<?php $value = '10';?>
<p class='actions'>Loading...</p>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<noscript>Javascript is disabled!</noscript>
<script>
$(function(){
    var str = 'value = <?=$value?>';
    $('.actions').text(str);
    console.log(str);
});
</script>
```